# Is it safe to backup a partition with dd?

Tags: image, dd

I'm doing a backup of a 2GB SD card (and its partition table, etc.) which contains 500 MB (1.5 GB unused) with

```
dd if=/dev/sdX | gzip > my_image.gz
```

It will backup the 500 MB of useful data but also potentially:

- some random data (harmless),
- zero data (harmless),
- or even personal data that was previously on the SD card in the "unused space" bytes, if the SD card was not previously erased with `dd if=/dev/zero ...`. Isn't this is a potential data leak?

**1) So is it safe to backup a SD card with `dd` that way**? (considered that some previously-deleted-personal-data might be saved in the backup!)

**2) Is there a way to "zero" all the unused space of the SD card before `dd`ing?**

Comment: Mount the usb drive, fill all the available space with a file (dd if=/dev/zero of=zerofile bs=32M), then delete the zerofile, unmount it, then dd it. No leftovers in there. Better dd it with ddrescue which also handles sparse files and takes up less space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it will work and yes, as you say, if you have any hidden, old data there, it will be stored in your image as well. So if you are worried about not storing those files, just use tar.

If you want to zero unused space you can use zerofree, check this thread:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44234/clear-unused-space-with-zeros-ext3-ext4
(assuming you're using ext3 or ext4).

Honestly, no idea how to do it with fat (which is what you're likely using if it's an sd), maybe the only way would be to tar everything, dd it to zero, and untar...

To recover that back-up you should dd it back to an SD that is at least as big as that one (if it's bigger, it will waste some space as the partition will be just 2Gb, but it will still work).

As I said in my comment, using dd is good when you need to preserve *everything*, such as boot sectors and partition configuration. If you don't have any of that, and you want to save the files there, use good ol' tar.

Comment: Yes  but some *previously-deleted-personal-data* might be saved in the backup, so this is not safe?

Comment: That's true, in that case, as Sobrique sugested, you should use tar, as it would only copy files, not raw partition data.

Comment: Sorry @MartinEZulliger  my question wasn't clear, I edited it: the question about "safe" was about deleted-but-not-zeroed-personal-data on the SD card. Maybe you can update the answer?

Comment: I used dd a lot because I needed to clone filesystems, and I didn't really care about the hidden data. The dd thing is good if you, like in my case, have boot files and special partition configuration you need to preserve.

Comment: Is there a way to "zero" all the unused space of the SD card before dding? (edited in my question)

Comment: Edited twice, you're making me work a lot here hahahaha

Comment: You should be aware that, if you were using a Windows-y filesystem like FAT-32 on the SD card, that the *names* of any deleted sensitive files may still be in the File Allocation Table (FAT) with the first letter changed to a question mark and the *name* is therefore potentially recoverable even if the data is not.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Reading a device with `dd` creates an image file, which you can `dd` straight back again. It's very similar to an `iso` that you'd prep for burning onto a CD.

The only downside of doing this is that you've got a disk image, not a structured filesystem. So you'll have some wasted space (a `dd` image includes empty space - this should get compressed away, but it'll also include whatever random junk is lying around deleted) and you'll also need to manually mount it if you want to extract a single file from it. This can be easier or harder depending on what OS you're using.

You may want to consider `ufsdump` or `tar` as alternatives though.

Comment: Some previously-deleted-personal-data (not freed by "zeroing" the deleted files)  will be saved in the backup, so this is not safe?